# Java: how to access class variables when using add(ClassName) in a JFrame

Tags: java, class, variables

I need to access two variables (`screenWidth` and `screenHeight`) that are within the `Surface` class. This is how I currently achieve that:

```
public class WheelOfFortune extends JFrame {

public WheelOfFortune() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    Surface newSurface = new Surface();

    add(newSurface);

    setSize(newSurface.screenWidth, newSurface.screenHeight);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        WheelOfFortune ex = new WheelOfFortune();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.setResizable(false);
    });
}

}
```

Is it possible to do the same by using this code? How?

```
public class WheelOfFortune extends JFrame {

public WheelOfFortune() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    add(new Surface());

    setTitle("The Wheel of Fortune");

    setSize(???.screenWidth, ???.screenHeight);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        WheelOfFortune ex = new WheelOfFortune();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.setResizable(false);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: One question: Why?

Comment: Less lines of code, curiosity and willingness to do things properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes:

```
setSize(((Surface)getComponent(getComponentCount()-1)).screenWidth, ((Surface)getComponent(getComponentCount()-1)).screenHeight);
```

No:

> See yes.

Your original solution is clean, short and proper.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Cheers.